# Custom Activities and Update to web.config with authorized types

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-actions

I have a vs solution with:

1. One class library with custom activities.
2. One sharepoint project with a mapped folder to the workflow folder in the 14 hive and the custom actions entries.
3. One sharepoint project with a feature that adds the authorized type to the web.config.

From my point of view this makes maintenance and subsequent deployments easier because:
If I add a new custom activity, I only need to update solution 2. not number 3.

What do you think? Would it be better to join 2+3 in one simple sharepoint project?

is there any ms article or blog that talks about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As neither 2 nor 3 makes any sense without the other I'd put them into a single project.

If it made sense to deploy 2 without 3 or the other way around then you should have two projects.